# "which" acting as relative pronoun standing for verbal phrases?

Tags: grammar, relative-pronouns

> 1: Metal will bear beating with a hammer, **which** a stone will not.
>
> 2: He can write a letter in English, **which** I cannot.

In these examples does "which" act as a relative pronoun and stand for the phrases of "bear beating with a hammer" and "write a letter in English" respectively in the above two sentences?

Comment: Yes,  you are right.

Answer (score 1):

While is the best choice here. In this context, 'while' expresses contrast. Consider the following examples for more claqrification:
-Henry went about preparing breakfast, while Bill rolled the blankets and made the sled ready.
-While he writes charmingly, he is not always truthful.
-While I have a certain amount of intelligence, I have no esthetic sense.
-while I possess the mathematical faculty, I am wholly without religious emotions.
-while I am addictied to venery, I have little ambition.
-While fire is hot, ice is cold.

### Sources:
A Modern English Grammar on Historical Principles, by Otto Jespersen - Part 4, Syntax

UNDERSTANDING AND USING FOURTH EDITION, Martha Hall and Betty S. Azar - TEACHER’S GUIDE

Comment: The question is asking about the grammatical role of 'which,' not about how the sentence might be improved.

Comment: Actually, the use of 'which' in the two sentences provided by the user is not correct.

Answer (score -1):

You should use [while](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/while) (sense 4b).

I can't say for sure, but I don't think *which* is normally used this way. In your example I think you need a conjunction.

Comment: *Which* is perfectly idiomatic here.

Comment: @StoneyB Does "which" stand for the phrases of "bear beating with a hammer" and "write a letter in English"? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @April That's how I would read them, yes.

Comment: @StoneyB  Thank you very much! You helped me a lot!